# jQuery - Add comma when press enter key

Tags: jquery, textarea, keypress, keyword

I have a textarea and i want type keywords into this and want it add comma automatically after press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, for example you type a words or sentence then you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and it will add comma after each words or .. i write a simple code but it have two problem, first it will add comma everytime you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it just will add comma after first words but i want it add comma after each words not just one. second problem is i dont want it goes to new line when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$('#formID').live("keypress", function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  $("textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, " ، "));
  });
}
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsFbN/100/)**

Comment: `\n` for new line , ie `replace(/\n/g, " ، ")`

Comment: something like this? combined with Pranavs code http://jsfiddle.net/HsFbN/103/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // alert($('textarea').val());
    $('textarea').val($('textarea').val() + ', ');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for question,
Try out below code once

```js
 $('textarea').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).val($(this).val() + ' , ')
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=formID><textarea></textarea><input type=submit></form>
```